# Finding Palindromes within a range in C?

Tags: c

I have written this code in C to find the palindromic numbers below a given range. But the program outputs only "1" for all number. I can't find my mistake.

Can you please help? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
int IsPalindromic (int n)
{
   int reverse,flag = 0;
   int temp = n;

   while( temp != 0 )
   {   reverse = reverse*10 + temp%10;
       temp = temp/10;  
   }

   if ( n == reverse ) flag=1;
   return flag;
}

 int main() 
 {
   int range,i,count=0;
   printf("Enter range:\n");
   scanf("%d",&range);

  for (i=1;i<range;i++) 
    {
      if (IsPalindromic(i)== 1)
      {
       printf ("%d \n",i);
      count++;
      }
   }
    printf ("Number of Palindromes under %d: %d",range,count);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: don't edit the code to fix it. it will confuse future readers.

Comment: Rolled back to question as asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line

```
reverse = reverse*10 + temp%10;
```

the local variable `reverse` has not been initiliased, therefore the program exhibits *undefined behaviour*.

You defined two variables but only initialised the second one with

```
int reverse,flag = 0;
```

I suggest this

```
int reverse = 0, flag = 0;
```

Comment: But I have initialised `int reverse = 0` on 2nd line.

Comment: No, you only initialised `flag`. You defined two variables but only initialised the second one. Edited answer.

Comment: thanks! I knew that initializing `int reverse,flag = 0;`, initializes both of them to 0. the code works now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly the dinamic of your program, but try also to edit the `i<range` with `i<=range`, if i starts from 1.

Comment: But the report is `printf ("Number of Palindromes under %d: %d",range,count);` note the "under".

Comment: Yes, exactly. Don't know if he considers "under" as a < or <=. Just a tip :) thank you

Comment: It's not an answer to his problem though, it's a comment.

Comment: Technically, `0` should be counted as a palindrome as well.